# Python - Disable nested for loop according to boolean value

Tags: python, loops, nested

What is the best way to rewrite nested for-loops like this:

```
for i in my_generator_function(args...):
    #do stuff...

    for j in another_generator_function(args...):
        #do more stuff
```

if i want to disable the first for-loop, according to a boolan value, but always keep the inner one? Of course I could use an if/else around it, and put a duplicate of the inner loop in the else block. but is there a better way?

Comment: i don't think that's even possible... Keeping the inner for loop running when you abort the parent loop?

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: I tried my best, to rephrase the code in my question to make clear, what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to loop `100` or `0` times through something and keep the inner `10`.

If that is what you want, try this:

```
my_value = False

checker = lambda x, y: y if x else range(1)

def somefunc():
    return range(100)

for i in checker(my_value, somefunc()):
    if my_value:
        #do stuff
    for j in range(10):
        #do stuff
```

Comment: OK, I see how this would work. But what if the sequence of the first loop is a function call, like `for resized in pyramid(image_center, scale=1.5, minSize=(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)):`

Comment: @kett What do you mean by that? The code will perform outer loop once if `my_value` is `False` and it will execute outer loop code only if `my_value` is `True` which basically disables it and just does the inner loop.

Comment: I edited the question, so you see what I mean. Basically, I can't put the `range(checker(my_value))` in there, because I'm iterating over a generator. I'm sorry, my original question with `range` was not well phrased.

Comment: @kett How about now?

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work for me, since the inner loop depends on the output of the first. In case the first one is deactivated, the inner one doesn't work anymore. I'd have to insert an if/else statement before the inner loop to catch that. So it's not really more elegant anymore, than just using an if/else for both cases in the first place. I guess we tried...:)

Comment: @kett Just to be clear, this did solve both problems you introduced with your question. Unfortunately, your issue seems to be elsewhere.